# Load ansible.cfg in each playbook dir

Tags: ansible, ansible-awx

I'm looking for a solution to load local ansible.cfg at root playbook_dir.
This is my architeture folder of playbooks:

```
ansible
├── deploy_manager
│   ├── ansible.cfg
│   ├── deploy_manager.yml
│   ├── environments
│   │   ├── demo
│   │   │   ├── group_vars
│   │   │   │   └── demo.yml
│   │   │   ├── inventory.yml
│   │   │   └── vars
│   │   │       └── vault.yml
│   │   ├── int
│   │   │   ├── group_vars
│   │   │   │   └── int.yml
│   │   │   ├── inventory.yml
│   │   │   └── vars
│   │   │       └── vault.yml
│   │   └── prod
│   │       ├── group_vars
│   │       │   └── prod.yml
│   │       ├── inventory.yml
│   │       └── vars
│   │           └── vault.yml
│   ├── README.md
│   └── roles
│       ├── create_instance
│       │   └── tasks
│       │       └── main.yml
```

When I execute the playbook with ansible-playbook cli, I have an ansible.cfg in current dir so ansible.cfg is loaded.

When I execute the playbook from AWX, the project is in tmp/cev039fj/awx_1900_tw78u5vh/project.
There is no ansible.cfg in /tmp/ cev039fj/awx_1900_tw78u5vh so it's the /etc/ansible/ansible.cfg which is loaded.
I have an ansible.cfg in each playbook directory with different params so how could I setup the ANSIBLE_CONFIG path to playbook dir ansible.cfg when a playbook is launched by AWX ?

I did some tests unsuccessful with ANSIBLE_CONFIG setup.

Have you any ideas ?

Thanks

**EDIT:**

I have open an issue to awx github https://github.com/ansible/awx/issues/10398
This is a limitation of AWX which loads ansible config to root project only because the playbook is executed at root of the project.
Usually, I execute playbook in current directory playbook that's why I have no problem with my specific ansible.cfg.
I made two proposals to resolve this problem, I will post the final point here when it will be finished

Comment: how `export ANSIBLE_CONFIG=.....` did not helped you ? you can also keep the config file in user's home directory as cfg of `/etc/` will be used as last resort.

Comment: I have several ansible.cfg in each playbook directory so I would need a dynamic ANSIBLE_CONFIG to the playbook directory path.
And I'm not sure how AWX use ANSIBLE_CONFIG variable. Just wait for the discussion with AWX dev

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I know that ansible-runner won't respect your callback_plugins setting here. It tries to respect the user settings for callback plugins, and append its own to the end of the list.

https://github.com/ansible/ansible-runner/blob/4926a6afda13e768f55010f46509d2888e83e9a7/ansible_runner/config/_base.py#L242

But the issue is that you didn't set the env var ANSIBLE_CALLBACK_PLUGINS. You set the config file setting for the same thing. To combine with that, it would have to read the config file. It doesn't.

However, AWX does read the config file in cases, so that it doesn't clobber the user settings. This is the wrong place to do it. That needs to be moved into ansible-runner so that it can take responsibility for properly over-riding existing user settings. Or else, Ansible core needs to add some syntax to denote "existing values of a list-valued setting".

There is 1 other way we could fix this - we could put the ansible-runner callback plugin in a collection in an expected location. See ansible/ansible-runner#482. This avoids the need for ansible-runner to change the ANSIBLE_CALLBACK_PLUGINS setting at all and it just references the standard out callback plugin. However, it would still need to set the ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK setting.

You are also setting the stdout callback setting. This doesn't make a lot of sense to me. There can only be 1 standard out callback plugin, because that's what dictates what gets written to standard out. I toyed with ideas for layering them, but they would step on each other's toes. Instead, I think you should consider doing your plugin as a "normal" callback plugin instead of a stdout callback plugin. If you do this, you can still enable it by changing the AWX_TASK_ENV setting without ansible-runner clobbering it. You can't do that with the config file - and that's our bug.